# Tricky slicing specifications on business-day datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a business-day-based DateTimeIndex.  For each month that's in the index, I also have a single 'marker' day specified.

Here's a toy version of that dataframe:

```
# a dataframe with business dates as the index
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(91)), pd.date_range('2015-04-01', '2015-6-30'), columns=['foo']).resample('B').last()

# each month has an single, arbitrary marker day specified
marker_dates = [df.index[12], df.index[33], df.index[57]]
```

For each month in the index, I need to calculate average of the `foo` column  in specific slice of rows in that month.

There are two different ways I need to be able to specify those slices:

**1)  m'th day to n'th day.**

Example might be (2rd to 4th business day in that month).  So april would be the average of 1 (apr2), 4 (apr3), and 5 (apr 6) = 3.33.  May would be 33 (may 4), 34 (may 5), 35 (may 6) = 34.    I don't consider the weekends/holidays that don't occur in the index as days.

**2) m'th day before/after the marker date to the n'th day before/after the marker date.**

Example might be "average of the slice from 1 day before the marker date to 1 day after the marker date in each month"   Eg. In April, the marker date is 17Apr.   Looking at the index, we want the average of apr16, apr17, and apr20.

For Example 1, I had an ugly solution that foreach month I would slice the rows of that month away, and then apply   `df_slice.iloc[m:n].mean()`

Whenever I start doing iterative things with pandas, I always suspect I'm doing it wrong.  So I imagine there is a cleaner, pythonic/vectorized way to make this result for all the months

For Example 2, I don't not know a good way to do this slice-averaging based on arbitrary dates across many months.

Comment: So you have the index and you want to take mean based on those indices?

Comment: @Dark yeah I have the indices and a column foo -- i want to take means on slices of foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BDay() from pandas.tseries.offsets

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay 

M=2
N=4

start_date = pd.datetime(2015,4,1)
end_date = pd.datetime(2015,6,30)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(91)), pd.date_range('2015-04-01', '2015-6-30'), columns=['foo']).resample('B').last()

# for month starts
marker_dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='BMS')

# create IntervalIndex
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([ (d + (M-1)*BDay(), d + (N-1)*BDay()) for d in marker_dates ], closed='both')

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, bins)).mean()
#[2015-04-02, 2015-04-06]   3.333333
#[2015-05-04, 2015-05-06]  34.000000
#[2015-06-02, 2015-06-04]  63.000000


# any markers
marker_dates = [df.index[12], df.index[33], df.index[57]]

# M Bday before, and N Bday after 
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([ (d - M*BDay(), d + N*BDay()) for d in marker_dates ], closed='both')

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, bins)).mean()
#[2015-04-15, 2015-04-23]  18.428571
#[2015-05-14, 2015-05-22]  48.000000
#[2015-06-17, 2015-06-25]  81.428571
```

Answer (score 3):

The most pythonic/vectorized (pandonic?) way to do this might be to use [df.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [df.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to generate the window over which you'll take the average, then [df.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to select the value at the dates you've marked.

For your example (2), this could look like:

```
df['foo'].rolling(3).mean().shift(-1).reindex(marker_dates)
Out[8]: 
2015-04-17    17.333333
2015-05-18    47.000000
2015-06-19    80.333333
Name: foo, dtype: float64
```

This could be wrapped in a small function:

```
def window_mean_at_indices(df, indices, begin=-1, end=1):
    return df.rolling(1+end-begin).mean().shift(-end).reindex(indices)
```

Helping to make it more clear how to apply this to situation (1):

```
month_starts = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='BMS')

month_starts
Out[11]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BMS')

window_mean_at_indices(df['foo'], month_starts, begin=1, end=3)
Out[12]: 
2015-04-01     3.333333
2015-05-01    34.000000
2015-06-01    63.000000
Freq: BMS, Name: foo, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem you can use grouper and iloc i.e

```
low = 2
high= 4

slice_mean = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0,freq='m')).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[low-1:high].mean())
# or df.resample('m').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[low-1:high].mean())
               foo
2015-04-30   3.333333
2015-05-31  34.000000
2015-06-30  63.000000
```

For your second problem you can concat the dates and take the groupy mean per month i.e

```
idx = pd.np.where(df.index.isin(pd.Series(marker_dates)))[0]

#array([12, 33, 57])
temp = pd.concat([df.iloc[(idx+i)] for i in [-1,0,1]])

            foo
2015-04-16   15
2015-05-15   46
2015-06-18   78
2015-04-17   18
2015-05-18   47
2015-06-19   81
2015-04-20   19
2015-05-19   48
2015-06-22   82

# Groupby mean
temp.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0,freq='m')).mean()
# or temp.resample('m').mean()
              foo
2015-04-30  17.333333
2015-05-31  47.000000
2015-06-30  80.333333
dtype: float64
```

since the index of output aint specified in the question do let us know what the index of output be.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I managed to come up with:

Import pandas and setup the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(91)), pd.date_range('2015-04-01', '2015-6-30'), columns=['foo']).resample('B')
```

Start with a pure list of marker dates, since I'm guessing that what you're really starting with:

```
marker_dates = [
    pd.to_datetime('2015-04-17', format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    pd.to_datetime('2015-05-18', format='%Y-%m-%d'),
    pd.to_datetime('2015-06-19', format='%Y-%m-%d')
]
marker_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['marker', 'start', 'end', 'avg'])
marker_df['marker'] = marker_dates
```

For the case where you want to just test ranges, input the start and end manually here instead of calculating it. If you want to change the range you can change the arguments to shift():

```
marker_df['start'] = df.index.shift(-1)[df.index.isin(marker_df['marker'])]
marker_df['end'] = df.index.shift(1)[df.index.isin(marker_df['marker'])]
```

Finally, use DataFrame.apply() to do a row by row calculation of averages:

```
marker_df.apply(
    lambda x: df[(x['start'] <= df.index) & (df.index <= x['end'])]['foo'].mean(), 
    axis=1
)
```

Which gives us this result:

```
      marker      start        end        avg
0 2015-04-17 2015-04-16 2015-04-20  17.000000
1 2015-05-18 2015-05-15 2015-05-19  46.666667
2 2015-06-19 2015-06-18 2015-06-22  80.000000
```